# Careers is nice, but can we center the footer?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, jobs, footer

[Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) is an impressive site. With the new addition of company pages I think the team at Stack Exchange did an excellent job. Hats off to you guys.

As I'm browsing the various Stack Exchange/Careers sites, I am noticing some minor inconsistencies with the user interface. Is it possible to center the footer of the Careers sites as to mimic the consistency of all other Stack Exchange sites?

Screen shot provided:

[image]

As you visit the site and scroll down, we go from a centered layout to a left aligned layout and it just doesn't flow as nicely as it should.

Comment: I actually kind of like it. The background of the footer should be a *slightly* different color, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other sites aren’t centered in the footer, but they have more content, and so appear more balanced. We’ve always got design tweaks in the works, will pass this on to our designer.