# What constitutes completeness in Careers 2.0?

Tags: discussion, jobs

[Careers as mentioned is a beautiful site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182516/careers-is-nice-but-can-we-center-the-footer)  But one thing that seems odd is what determines if a profile is complete:

[image]

This is a nice stat telling me how close I am to completing my profile.  But shouldn't I determine whether I have completed my profile or not.  For instance, how can I ever reach `210` (value of a complete profile) if I don't have a website URL.  The text below my score tells me ways I can improve my profile to complete it.  For instance, it states `Masters of Scienc...needs expanding achievements`.  In this case I no longer have any further achievements to be listed (At least none I am proud of :) ).

In this case there should be an option / selection that states `No other achievements available` this will signify to my "Completeness Profile" not to further look into this point.

What I am asking here is should we even worry about or display a completeness rating, isn't this something that I the candidate determines?  To me these are simply extras, they should not factor the "completeness" of my profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having a maxed out completeness is not necessary, it's simply there to point out things that we expect would make your profile better for the employers on our site.  I don't even have a maxed out completeness score and in fact if you have a completeness score of 140 or more, you are in the top 20% of all people on our site.  Rest assured that the completeness score does not directly affect your order in search results with the exception of the "show me everyone" search.  It does give you a rough indication of the typical location of your profile in search results however.

As for the achievements in education and experience, we did some statistical analysis of profiles which received more messages and found that around 120 characters for education listings was the sweet spot and around 400-500 or so was the sweet spot for experience.  The character counts we chose for these sections was meant to be slightly on the low end of those ranges.  Of note, older experience and education sections tend to have fewer characters about them.  This was not found to be an issue and is part of my score not maxing out.

Comment: I still think you get to a point where the candidate asks himself am I complete, yes or no.  If I am I should be given a score that is equal to the maximum score of a profile.  I'm also not sure why you guys used such a scoring system, why 210?  Why not a percentage?

Comment: @JonH: re "Why not a percentage?" Perhaps because most people, myself included, add and subtract in our heads faster than we divide by unusual denominators.

Comment: @JonH It didn't start out as 210, I believe it was originally 180ish, but it's grown as we have added features.  We expected to add features and we never wanted your score to go down as a result of that, so the arbitrary cap is just because that's how it worked out, sort of like achievement points in many gaming systems.